# How to calculate exchange rate from this data

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a been given a task. I need to use the currencies from [this source](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml) to work out the exchange rate between 2 currencies. Requirements are that I need to use that data source and, select a date, the amount to calculate and the two currencies.

The rates on that feed are based against the euro as the base currency. Is there any way that I can use that data to work out the exchange rate between say, 100 GBP in USD?

```
> currency="USD" rate="1.3186"
> currency="GBP" rate="0.86205"
```

100 GBP = ? USD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a rate of $1.3186$ for $\$$ to €, this means that $1€ = 1.3186\$$. 
Furthermore $1€ = 0.86205 £$. Then we can use this information to get
\begin{align}& 1.3186\$  =1€ = 0.86205 £  \\
\Leftrightarrow & \frac{1.3186}{0.86205}\$ = 1.646\$= 1£
\end{align}
Now you know, that 1£ is equivalent to $1.528\$$. Now simply multiply by 100.

Comment: Marginal point, but you need to assume an efficient market (ie, no arbitrage opportunities), otherwise transitivity does not hold...

Comment: Correct, but I think this is a justified assumption in this case.

Comment: Just being a pedant :-).

Comment: Great thanks, this really helped

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are no arbitrage opportunities you will have $1 € = 1.3186  \$$ and $1 € = 0.86205 £$. Hence $1 \$ = \frac{1}{1.3186} € = \frac{1}{1.3186} (0.86205) £ \approx 0.6538 £$.

Hence $100 £ \approx \frac{100}{0.6538} \$ = 153.0 \$$.

Comment: I stole your £ sign as I didn't have it on my keyboard ;)
Note that OP is askingfor £ to $, not $ to £.

Comment: @macydanim: I just 'Google' for uk pound and euro to grab the symbols. I have no idea how to synthesize those symbols on my little keyboard!

Comment: € is made via AltGr+E

Comment: Brings up the Edit menu on Firefox in windoze.

Comment: Hm not on german keyboards, sorry ;)